# Is yea an acceptable replacement for yeah?

Tags: word-usage

I'm an amateur writer, writing almost entirely fanfiction, and I use the word 'yea' in my writings rather often instead of yeah. In sentences like "If you mean did that just happen? Yea." or "Yea... I'm gonna need another cup of coffee before dealing with this."

I know that originally Yea was the opposite of Nay but more and more I'm seeing people use it in place of Yeah, dropping the h. Is that becoming the correct way, an acceptable way, of saying it or am I just mistaken?

Comment: Looks clumsy to me. I still read it as rhyming with ‘nay’, not ‘bear’ (in non-rhotic accents). If anything, I'd drop the e and write ‘yah’, to rhyme with ‘nah’.

Comment: It depends (in my opinion) on your character's "voice". You might write a character's spoken dialect with any phonetic spellings you wish. Otherwise, I think you should stick to "Yes".

Comment: 'Yea' for 'yeah' seems perfectly reasonable to me but the Google Ngram suggests otherwise.  'Yea' appears to be linked to 'nay."  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yea%2Cyeah%2Cnay&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyeah%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnay%3B%2Cc0

Comment: yeah, I've been seeing it too, and I predict in a decade  it will be pretty much the accepted spelling. But if you're writing "yeah", there's no other spelling right now. Yea still surprises, ya seems like yuh, yah sounds like nah... right now, I'd still stick with *yeah*.

Comment: Fan fiction is not formal writing; take opinions from [writers.se], which should be more useful to you. ELU will frown upon the use of *yea* for *yeah* (in formal writing).

Comment: Suggested migration to writers.se

Comment: I'm asking, not for the sake of fanfiction, but for the sake of knowing. If it's an acceptable replacement in general.

Comment: @Selonianth - can we help you further? If we can, edit your post with the new question, and someone will answer.

Comment: It's a bit hard to pinpoint a time when "acceptability" begins; I leave that to the dictionaries. As a writer, I'd be hesitant to put newfangled variants into my writing until dictionary editors started putting those variants between their covers. After checking out the definitions, example usages, and pronuncations listed under several dictionary entries for [yeah](http://www.onelook.com/?w=yeah), [yea](http://www.onelook.com/?w=yea&ls=a), and even [yah](http://www.onelook.com/?w=yah), I'd be inclined to keep my _h_.

Comment: ...Yeah verily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Yea' is a real but antiquated word, still in use in various contexts e.g. 'Whose job is it to say *yea* or *nay*?

'Yeah' is the representation of an informal pronunciation of 'yes'.  (OED).

So if you are reporting informal speech I would suggest you stick with 'yeah'.

Answer (score 0):

To assess whether a spelling is considered correct, your best bet is to check a couple of dictionaries. Once the spelling passes into acceptabled use, dictionaries will record it it. I would *not* use alternative spellings until either: (1) they become standardized, or (2) you are trying to write a specific dialect. Even then, it's better to write dialect using correctly spelled words, but choosing words that reflect that region, rather than misspelling, collapsing a word together, or using other methods.

Two other things: even if a dictionary lists the spelling as correct, remember that the *first* entry is the *most* proper entry; and, I would refrain from using a word that can be misconstrued by your readers. For instance, If I read *yea* in your text, I would read it as *yā*, either as "Yay, he did it!" or as the older *yea* and *nay*, and then wonder why you're including Early Modern English into your text.

Comment: The first entry in a dictionary is not necessarily the most proper, it is just the one used in that particular dictionary. I would never, ever read ‘yea’ as ‘yay, hurray’. They are homophonous, but mean _completely_ different things to me.

Comment: For example, many dictionaries list things in order of etymological age rather than frequency of use.

Comment: Because it is homophonous, I would wonder if that is exactly what they were attempting to write, especially if the context allowed for both definitions. I was thinking something like, "You're going to the pool? Yea, so am I."  Both "Yeah, so am I" (_yeah_ being used as a filler word as is common in certain regions and dialects), and "hurray, so am I" work here.

Comment: Also, as far as entries are concerned, it depends on the dictionary. For most normal dictionaries, what I typed above is correct. For instance, it is explained in the Merriam-Webster dictionary that only multiple words joined by "or" and in alphabetical order are truly equal variants. All others, including words joined by "or" that are out of alphabetical order, are not true equal variants and as such, the first one is preferred. 

Etymological dictionaries, or "lexicons" are special dictionaries that list root words first. They are not common dictionaries used in everyday life.

Answer (score -1):

*Yea* **is** equivalent to *yeah*, just not in common usage. *Yea* sounds a bit more suited for a futuristic rather than a contemporary setting.